# how answer a phone call with python through serial port?

Tags: python, phone-call

I've been trying to answer a phone call using a serial port, but i only get `'RING\r\n'` and after a while `'NO CARRIER'`. is there any command to answer a call?

```
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial() 
ser.port='COM3' 
ser.baudrate=9600 
ser.open() 
while True: 
    lectura = ser.readline() 
    if lectura == "RING": ser.write("OK") # To answer the call.
```

Comment: `import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port='COM3'
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.open()
while True:
 lectura = ser.readline()
 if lectura == "RING":
  ser.write("OK") # To answer the call.`

Comment: I proved using a phone and when i answer a call, it generate the string 'OK'. I've tried search a kind of protocol for it, but i have nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

You just have to send the ACK character.

```
ser.write(b'\x06')
```

Comment: Please include the code in your answer as text, not as an image. This will make it easier for others to see and work with.

Comment: It's because is a character ascii and in that way shows sublime text. The original code is `code` ser.write('') `code`